# There is a simple way to get unix time range of a day if given a random timestamp from that day?

Tags: php, time

There is a simple way to get unix time range of a day if given a random timestamp from that day ?
I have a date like 1345547471 which is "Tue, 21 Aug 2012 11:11:11 GMT"

There is a php function that can receive a timestamp like this and return a 00:00 hours timestamp and a 23:59 hours timestamp of that day ?

Thank you.

Comment: get  year, month and day from the timestamp and create the timestamp with 00 hour and 00 minute, then do the same with 23 hour and 59 min i don't think that's difficult

Comment: Which time zone are you interested in?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the `mod` (gives the remainder after a division) PHP function like this to get the first second of a Unix timestamp (ie, today 0:00:00)

```
$var=time()-(time()%86400);
```

Then with this unix timstamp, you can add 86399 to get the last second of the day.

Edit: This doesn't account for dalylight savings.

Comment: @PeterSzymkowski Thanks mate, old school tricks before all these fancy `DateTime` classes were introduced :)

Comment: This assumes that there 86400 seconds in a day, which is not always the case (daylight savings time, local time discontinuity).

Comment: @nickb as far i know unix timestamp it is not affected by leap seconds

Comment: @PeterSzymkowski But as Nickb points out correctly, it can be offset by daylight savings and the like.

Comment: @Fluffeh not true :) Check this out http://codepad.viper-7.com/AJVr7P - As i said unix timestamp is not affected by leap seconds - 86400 is always one day

Comment: @Peter - You're confusing *leap year* with *daylight savings time*, which are two different things. In DST, a day can have 23 or 25 hours.

Comment: @PeterSzymkowski Yes, but it won't account for [Daylight savings time](http://www.timeanddate.com/time/dst/2013.html) which is *not* accounted for via the unix timestamp and shortens/lengthens days by an hour during the year. Having said that, I would love to know if `DateTime` accurately *does* account for all the local changes.

Comment: `DateTime->getTimestamp()` will always give you same result as Fluffeh solution. Am i wrong?

Comment: @Peter - I don't believe so, here's my rationale: Let's assume today was the day clocks went forward for DST. So, as 01:59 local time advanced to the next minute, the time went from 01:59 to 03:00. Now, today will only have 23 hours in the day, and when you add 86399 seconds to today's midnight timestamp, you would (incorrectly) get 00:59 of tomorrow. See [this Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Day): "A civil day is usually also 86,400 seconds, ... occasionally plus or minus an hour when changing from or to daylight saving time"

Comment: @nickb But it's not a date it's TIMESTAMP :) Lets assume we have two functions: `nickb($ts)` and `fluffeh($ts)`. Please give me `$ts` argument for which functions will return different results.

Comment: @nickb check this out http://codepad.viper-7.com/sYhGQl - you guys are confusing Timestamp with DateTime

Comment: @Peter - What about when you [introduce time zones](http://codepad.viper-7.com/84RtYo)? Then it [falls apart](http://viper-7.com/fPguDC), where DateTime handles it correctly (Note that 2:30AM didn't exist, which is why it's 3:30AM).

Comment: @nickb again you are confusing Unix timestamp and DateTime. UNIX Timestamp is always UTC/GMT - http://codepad.viper-7.com/hKp8A6

Comment: @nickb Anyways i know what you are trying to say and i agree :D

Answer (score 7):

Sure, [DateTime](http://www.php.net/datetime) can do that:

```
$time = 1345547471;
$date = new DateTime;
// $date->setTimezone( new DateTimeZone( "America/New_York")); // Can set TZ here if needed
$date->setTimestamp( $time);
```

Now, you can set the time to whatever you want:

```
$date->setTime( 0, 0, 0); // 0h 0m 0s
```

And grab the resulting UNIX Timestamp:

```
$timestamp = $date->getTimestamp();
```

Same thing for the next use-case:

```
$date->setTime( 23, 59, 0);
$timestamp = $date->getTimestamp();
```

It is important to note that DateTime will properly handle cases of daylight savings time and local time discontinuities.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ts = 1345547471;

$ts_00_00 = mktime(0,0,0, date("m", $ts), date("d",$ts), date("Y",$ts);
$ts_23_59 = mktime(23,59,59, date("m", $ts), date("d",$ts), date("Y",$ts);
```

Documentation:

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/function.mktime.php

Answer (score 0):

If you are using PHP >= 5.3.0 Then you can use this...
Check out for this.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php

Answer (score 0):

This is similar to Fluffeh's answer, but accounts for daylight savings time. This is based on the server's time zone.

```
//Get time range for today
$start = strtotime(date("Y-m-d")." 00:00:00");
$end = strtotime(date("Y-m-d")." 23:59:59");

//Show our date in a human-readable format for troubleshooting
echo date(DATE_RFC1036,$start)."<br>".date(DATE_RFC1036,$end);
```

If you want to specify a custom timezone instead of the server timezine, you can add it to like so:

```
//Get time range for today
$start = strtotime(date("Y-m-d")." 00:00:00 -0500");
$end = strtotime(date("Y-m-d")." 23:59:59 -0500");

//Show our date in a human-readable format for troubleshooting
echo date(DATE_RFC1036,$start)."<br>".date(DATE_RFC1036,$end);
```

[Link to working Sample](http://rextester.com/RNNE95553)